# Copy formula from another worksheet based on cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

**Background:**
I have a worksheet 'Guide Outputs' with columns A:AE. Each column has it's own formula, however, not every cell in the column has a formula (Sometimes I need to overwrite it with plain text).

**Problem:**
Sometimes I need to update the formulas, but cannot do a simple cut and paste for the entire column, because I don't want to overwrite the cells with plain text.

**What I need:**
Macro that copies the updated formula from worksheet 'Data' based on the column reference of the cell on worksheet 'Guide Outputs':

1. When I click 'Update' button,
2. On worksheet 'Guide Outputs' find all cells in column with formula,
3. Lookup that column on worksheet 'Data',
4. Copy formula from worksheet 'Data' cell(col=reference,row=3),
5. Paste into all cells with formulas in selected column on worksheet
   'Guide Outputs',
6. Repeat for each column.

End result should be that all cells with formulas get updated with the correct formula and the cells with plain text are ignored.

This could be done one cell at a time, but doing entire column at a time should be faster because there are hundreds of rows.

**Example:**

- Worksheet 'Guide Outputs' C11, C20, C36, C100 have formula, so
  copy/paste updated formula from worksheet 'Data' C3.
- Worksheet 'Guide Outputs' K3, K15, K88, K120 have formula, so
  copy/paste updated formula from worksheet 'Data' K3.

I am pretty advanced with formulas, but a newb at VBA. I can record macros and mash stuff together that I find online but that's about it!

Sorry but I could not even find anything to get started with.

Comment: Maybe try like this : `With Sheets("Guide Outputs"): 
Set rg = .Range("A3:AAJ100"): 
End With` ---> set the range of data. Then loop to each column in rg: `For Each col In rg.Columns: If Not Intersect(col, rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)) Is Nothing Then col.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Formula = Sheets("Data").Cells(col.Column, 3).Formula: end if: next: end sub` It check if looped column of rg has formula then it change the all cells with formula in the looped column with the one in the sheets Data respecting column, row 3.

Comment: @karma Switch the row and column in `.Cells`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, oops.... thank you for the correction. I just tested my code to run with dummy data, it turned out my code don't give an expected result if the row with formula is not starting in row 3. I shoud use the loop and copy method instead of `.formula = .formula`. Your code work beautifully.

Comment: Correcting my previous code in my comment, after `if not intersect` line, `frm = Sheets("Data").Cells(3, col.Column).Formula` ---> this is to get the formula into frm variable. Then `With col.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas): frm = Replace(frm, "3", .Cells.Row): .Formula = frm: End With`. So to fill all cells (contain formula) within the looped column with new formula at the same time, the previous frm where row 3 is replaced with the first row of cell contain formula within the looped column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update Formulas Only in Cells Containing Formulas

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UdateFormulas()

    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Data"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Guide Outputs"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range
    With dws.UsedRange
        Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).Resize(, drg.Columns.Count)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dvrg As Range, dcrg As Range, c As Long
    
    For Each dcrg In drg.Columns
        c = c + 1
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dvrg = dcrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dvrg Is Nothing Then
            srg.Cells(c).Copy dvrg
            Set dvrg = Nothing
        'Else ' no formula in column; do nothing
        End If
    Next dcrg
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    MsgBox "Formulas updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that worked great! I will do some testing but it looks like you nailed it. Thanks so much. :-)

Comment: Your formula seems to be copying the formatting too. Is there a way to do it like with the paste special where it pastes only the formula?