# Copy formula from another worksheet based on cell reference for a single row

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

This is very similar to my previous post, but instead of copying formulas to all of the rows, I need to just copy the formulas to a single row. [Copy formula from another worksheet based on cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878464/copy-formula-from-another-worksheet-based-on-cell-reference)

**Background:** I have a worksheet 'Guide Outputs' with columns A:AE. Each column has it's own formula, however, not every cell in the column has a formula (Sometimes I need to overwrite it with plain text).

**Problem:** I have a button that inserts a new row above the selected row and then pastes the formulas from worksheet 'Data' into the new row. The problem is that inserting the new row breaks the cell references of the formulas in the row below.

So I need to update the formulas, but cannot do a simple cut and paste for the entire row, because I don't want to overwrite any cells where the formulas have been replaced with plain text.

**What I need:** Macro that copies the updated formula from worksheet 'Data' based on the column reference of the cell on worksheet 'Guide Outputs':

1. When I click 'Add Row' button,
2. Insert a new row on worksheet 'Guide Outputs' and copy formulas from worksheet 'Data' (This part works fine),
3. On worksheet 'Guide Outputs', in the row below the inserted row, find all cells with formulas,
4. Lookup the columns on worksheet 'Data',
5. Copy formula from worksheet 'Data' cell(col=reference,row=3),
6. Paste into the cells that contain formulas for the row on worksheet 'Guide Outputs' (each column has a different formula),
7. Repeat for each cell.
8. End result should be that all cells with formulas get updated with the correct formula and the cells with plain text are ignored.

This should only update the single row below the inserted row in order to 'fix' the broken formulas.

The formulas on the 'Data' worksheet are in cells B3:AE3.

**Example:**

Worksheet 'Guide Outputs' H11, L11, M11, R11 have formula, so copy/paste formulas from worksheet 'Data' H3, L3, M3, R3.

Worksheet 'Guide Outputs' B20, C20, L20, M20 have formula, so copy/paste updated formula from worksheet 'Data' B3, C3, L3, M3.

I am pretty advanced with formulas, but a newb at VBA. I can record macros and mash stuff together that I find online but that's about it!

This is very similar to my previous post, but instead of copying formulas to all of the rows, I need to just copy the formulas to a single row. [Copy formula from another worksheet based on cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878464/copy-formula-from-another-worksheet-based-on-cell-reference)

Here's the part that works, ie inserting the new row, copying the formulas and making the text blue.

I need something that now fixes the broken formulas in the row below.

```
    Sub AddRow_Click()
    '
    ' AddRow Macro
    '
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets("Data").Range("B3:AE3").Copy
        Sheets("Guide Outputs").Select
    
        With ActiveCell
            Range("B" & .Row & ":AE" & .Row).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does inserting a row break the formula?

Comment: The formula references a cell in the row above, so inserting a row causes the formula to now reference the cell above the inserted row instead of the cell in the inserted row.

Comment: Maybe try like this ... `On Error Resume Next: Set rg = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas): If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub` ---> this will get all cells (below the inserted row) which has formula as rg variable. Then loop `for each cell in rg` .... fill the looped cell with the formula from sheet Data by copying ----> `Sheets("DATA").Range(Replace(cell.Address, "$" & rg.Row, "$" & 3)).Copy Destination:=cell` .... `next`. If there is a possibility that the row under the inserted row has no formula at all, then  need to check first to avoid error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, cell As Range

Selection.EntireRow.Insert
On Error Resume Next
Set rg = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete: Exit Sub

For Each cell In rg
Sheets("DATA").Range(Replace(cell.Address, "$" & rg.Row, "$" & 3)).Copy Destination:=cell
Next

End Sub
```

Set rg as the range of all cells which has formula in the row below the inserted row. If it can't create the rg, use the error trap, delete the inserted row and then exit the sub.

Then loop to each cell (which has formula) in rg, then get the formula in sheet DATA by replacing the looped cell address row number to 3, copy the formula into the looped cell.

That's if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from the previous answer, I have amended it slightly.  I think it now works with your data set.

```
Sub UdateFormulas()

Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Data"
Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"

Const DST_SHEET As String = "Guide Outputs"
Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3"

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
Dim drg As Range

Set drg = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AE" & ActiveCell.Row)


Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
Dim srg As Range:
Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).Resize(1, drg.Columns.Count)


'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim dvrg As Object, dcrg As Object, c As Long

For Each dcrg In drg
dcrg.Activate
    c = c + 1
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dvrg = dcrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Cells(1, 1)
     
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dvrg Is Nothing Then

    
        dcrg = srg.Cells(1, c + 1).FormulaR1C1
      
        Set dvrg = Nothing
    'Else ' no formula in column; do nothing
    End If
Next dcrg

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox "Formulas updated.", vbInformation
```

End Sub

Adding the link to the original post so it doesn't appear plagiarized:
[Copy formula from another worksheet based on cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878464/copy-formula-from-another-worksheet-based-on-cell-reference)

Comment: The problem with this is that every column has a different formula and they are quite complex, so I really don't want to have to manually adjust them. I just want to be able to copy the 'good' formulas from the 'Data' worksheet.

Comment: I basically just want to take the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878464/copy-formula-from-another-worksheet-based-on-cell-reference and adjust it so that it only updates a single row.

Comment: Repasting the formulas on the row below as well as the inserted row would be the solution except that sometimes the formulas get overwritten with plain text and that needs to be preserved.

Comment: That was my thought also, to just change the range, but it still updates everything in the worksheet. I think the problem is with the .Columns but I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: I think you're right, sorry, I should have removed the .columns from the range in For Each also.  As I don't have your data it is tricky to test.  Does it work if you do this?  (edited).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I am happy to send you a copy of the excel file if there is a way for me to do that?

Comment: you could put it on OneDrive and send me a link?

Comment: Is there a way to DM you the link?

Comment: I can't see one, and I'm not sure if we're allowed to share email addresses!  Could you do a mock sheet with 2 or 3 lines of anonymised data and then link it publicly on here?  (That might help others answer your question also)

Comment: I hope I have solved it now!(?)